# Column names in mysql, or change in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Some of my column names in mysql are becoming rather large around 25 characters. This is purely as I an echo the column name directly to the client rather than making a function in php to generate the name based on the mysql column.

Should this matter? Or should I use shorter column names and build a PHP that then uses the shorter column names and returns the actual name of what I want it to be?

Thanks

Comment: did anyone else understand this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use column aliases in your SQL query:

```
SELECT ReallyLongColumnName AS name ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The column names in the database are not meant for the user, they're purely internal labels. Just think about if you want to change some phrasing slightly, like using *Name of User* instead of `username`. Such a change may happen at any time and should not influence your database at all. Or what about localizing the names into different languages?

Therefore, use sensible, "technical" column names in your database and keep the user interface separate from them.

Comment: Yes it is not that, I am building a php game as a personal project and it is the game items I am having problems with, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go the PHP way.

You shouldn't be directly displaying the database columns to the customers - it's a violation of the principles of MVC isolation. The database column name is part of the model (M), and the customer is seeing the view (V). It's poor design to assume the two have a direct correspondence.

Comment: In some cases it is unavoidable to show at least parts of the model. Is an MVC isolation issue a problem on project that doesn't use MVC? I ask because either you're statement is conflated or my understanding of design patterns is well off.

Comment: @SOliver It's general isolation of concerns: the names of the columns in the database are fetch-handles, not view strings. They can't be i18nized, nor contain certain characters, not exceed certain lengths... They're not meant to be directly presented.

Comment: Hmm I agree that they generally shouldn't be used but I don't think the limitations of the naming convention for columns adequately vilifies there use.